# JPQL getResultList cast to class with more attributes than selected from database

Tags: java, jpa, constructor, jpql

I'm trying to do something like:

```
List<Report> results = new ArrayList<Report>();
results = em.createQuery("SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.workEmail FROM Employee u", Report.class)
                        .getResultList();
```

However, Report has more attributes than the 3 columns selected from the database(and does not have a specific constructor for those exact 3 attributes), so results is turned into a Vector of Object instead of an ArrayList of Report.
Is there a way to keep the results as an ArrayList and make all the other attributes of Report null ?

Comment: The object will be the same, only difference is in the populated data.

Comment: Why do you need the other fields nulled out?  Seems counter productive when the entity with all its data might already be cached.  If the user only needs those 3 fields visible, the display should only show the 3 fields and ignore the rest rather than rely on nulling out data.  An alternative is to create a non-entity data class with a constructor with those 3 fields that you can pass around as needed.  What you are attempting with Report is not a great idea as JPA is required to return managed entities - it would be all to easy for the incomplete data to be merged back into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List data =em.createQuery("SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.workEmail FROM Employee u", Report.class)
                    .getResultList();
 List<Report> results = new ArrayList<Report>();

 for (Object object : data) {
    Map row = (Map) object;
    Report report = new Report();
    report.setFirstName(row.get("0"));
    report.setLastName(row.get("1"));
    report.setWorkEmail (row.get("2"));
    results.add(report); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options, although I am not sure if the short one will work

Long option:

First subclass Report, add to the new class a constructor with the fields you want

```
public class MyReport extends Report {
   public MyReport(String firstname, String lastname, String workEmail) {
   ...
   }
}
```

And use the `SELECT NEW` construct

```
SELECT new MyReport(u.firstname, u.lastname, u.workEmail) FROM Employee u
```

Short option:

Exactly the same, but instead of creating a subclass, just implement the constructor in `Report`. I do not remember anything that would forbid this, but anyway I would test it carefully.

Comment: Oh and the `ArrayList vs Vector` issue is a fake one. The spec tells you that you will receive a `List`, so just do not make any assumption about which concrete implementation you will receive (it could be one provided by the JPA provider, he is not restricted to just API classes).

Comment: Unfortunately creating specific constructors isn't an option because Report has about 25 attributes that could be selected in any combination.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly: no. Of course you will get a RuntimeException if you try to execute your query as described above. The only solutions are:

**Solution 1** As @Prabhakaran wrote and you noticed, use the selected strings in order to create a new Report like this:

```
List data =em.createQuery("SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.workEmail FROM Employee u", Report.class).getResultList();
List<Report> results = new ArrayList<Report>();
for (Object object : data) {
   Map row = (Map) object;
   Report report = new Report();
   String firstName = row.get("0");
   String lastName = row.get("1");
   String lastEmail = row.get("2");
   results.add(new Report(firstName, null,..., lastName, ..., lastEmail)); 
}
```

**Solution 2**
As @SJuan76 said: use `SELECT NEW` and make a new constructor in Report with only three fields.